# Div with server tags style display from codebehind function

Tags: asp.net

I have this piece of ASPX code

```
<asp:Label id="TESTLBLTEST" runat="server" text="Can you see me Label" Visible="<%# DisplayVisibleFalse() %>"></asp:Label>
<div id="div_HID_IntermediateInfos" runat="server" style="display: <%= DisplayNone() %>">
    Can you see me DIV?
</div>
```

And these are code-behind functions:

```
Public Function DisplayNone() As String
    Dim OutShow As String = ""
    If csFunc.getUserHTTP = "myUname" Then
        OutShow = "block"
    Else
        OutShow = "none"
    End If
    Return OutShow
End Function
Public Function DisplayVisibleFalse() As Boolean
    Dim OutShow As Boolean = False
    If csFunc.getUserHTTP = "myUname" Then
        OutShow = True
    Else
        OutShow = False
    End If
    Return OutShow
End Function
```

I can't seem to call the two functions, tried different server tags etc. but none of the two functions is called. Both controls are displayed/visible on postback.

This is being used in a UserControl wchich has a parent page, this parent page also has a MasterPage.

Comment: What you want to use instead is an `asp:Panel` server side control. It renders as a div to the client. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cd2zztdd(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you **really** want to call these two functions, use this on your code-behind

```
TESTLBLTEST.Visible = DisplayVisibleFalse()
```

And remove the `runat="server"` from your div

```
<div id="div_HID_IntermediateInfos" style="display: <%= DisplayNone() %>">
```

But, as mentioned before, you should be using `<asp:Panel>` instead.

Comment: Decided to rewrite some code and use Panels instead of divs, will accept your answer although @asawyer in the comment was first to suggest it.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you directly try

```
div_HID_IntermediateInfos.Visible = True
```

And

```
div_HID_IntermediateInfos.Visible = False
```